# ¿Como limitar el incremento de un valor dependiendo de uno ya establecido en un input?

Tags: javascript

En esté código quiero limitar el incremento dependiendo de los números establecidos en el `input`

```js
var contador = 0;
var c = document.getElementById("lol");

function incrementar() {
  if (contador == c) {
    alert('Maximo permitido alcanzado:' + 'lol');
  } else {
    document.caca.muchacaca.value = contador++;
  }
}

function decrementar() {
  if (contador == 0) {
    alert('Minimo permitido alcanzado: 0');
  } else {
    document.caca.muchacaca.value = contador--;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="caca">
  <input id="lol" type="text" value="5" readonly="readonly">

  <br>

  <input type="button" onClick="incrementar()" value="aumentar">
  <input type="button" onClick="decrementar()" value="disminuir">
  <label> 
    <input name="muchacaca" type="text" readonly="readonly"> 
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: te falta tomar el valor del input , en la variable c termina el `document.getElementById('lol').value;`

Comment: edite la respuesta , para que funcione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que `c` es el `DOMElement` con `id="lol"`, cuando lo que realmente necesitas es el `value` de dicho elemento.

### Solución:

Para obtener el valor numérico guardado en el `input` pudes usar [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) (*entero*)  o [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat) (*con decimales*)

#### Ejemplo

```js
var contador = 0;
// AQUI obtenemos el value como número entero
var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("lol").value, 10);

function incrementar() {
  if (contador == c) {
    alert('Maximo permitido alcanzado:' + 'lol');
  } else {
    document.caca.muchacaca.value = contador++;
  }
}

function decrementar() {
  if (contador == 0) {
    alert('Minimo permitido alcanzado: 0');
  } else {
    document.caca.muchacaca.value = contador--;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="caca">
  <input id="lol" type="text" value="5" readonly="readonly">

  <br>

  <input type="button" onClick="incrementar()" value="aumentar">
  <input type="button" onClick="decrementar()" value="disminuir">
  <label> 
    <input name="muchacaca" type="text" readonly="readonly"> 
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Hermano, te la haz marcado, si tan solo me pudieras explicar porque después del value colocas un valor 
(.value, 10))

Comment: @BenEscobar, si lees la documentación de `parseInt` (link en la respuesta) el segundo parámetro es la base sobre la cual se ha de calcular el número entero.

Comment: Ah si, de hecho ayer ya me pusé a investigar algo así y ya encontré la solución, gracias de nuevo!